# fill 3-dimensional array(jagged array) with point data

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

I do have a 3-dimensional matrix

```
private int[][][] Matrix
```

but I dont know how to fill this. 
the first dimension is for my slices of a picture
the second for my x-values of one slice ad the 3rd slice for my y-values.

so das anybody know how to fill this arrays with some data for testing?

thanks

Comment: Why do you want a Jagged Array? It would be easier to have a list of objects in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Matrix = new int[5][][]; // 5 slices
Matrix[0] = new int[3][]; // 3 x values for the first slice
Matrix[0][0] = new int[2]; // 2 y values for the first x value in the first slice
```

But I don't think that you should use something like this. It is very error prone.

I suggest something like this:

```
class Slice
{
    public IList<XValue> XValues {get; set; }
}

class XValue
{
    public IList<YValue> YValues {get; set; }
}

class YValue
{
    // ...
}

var slices = new List<Slice>();
```

Comment: and how can i add values now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use array literals to create arrays of arrays of arrays:

```
private int[][][] Matrix = {
  {
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5}
  },
  {
    {1,2},
    {3},
    {4,5,6,7,8},
    {9,10}
  },
  {
    {1,2,3}
  }
};
```

Note that this is a jagged array, so different subarrays can have different number of items. If you want a three dimensional matrix you might want the three dimensional array `int[,,]` instead of nested one dimensional arrays.